# Custom static page url rewrite

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I would like to make my static HTML page part of my wordpress website. I would like to have no `.html` extension at the end of the url address.

name of my page: `info.html`

current URL: `www.website.com/info.html`

ideal URL: `www.website.com/info`

I know I can make the custom page template, but all the pages that I'd like to implement it in the website are completely different.

I've tried with .htaccess:

```
# URL Rewrite
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule (.*)info\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it does not work. I do not want to damage something!

Answer (score 3):

Update your permalinks

> Settings -> permalinks -> select (Post name) -> save

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```